# how to make <> not encode in TinyMCE

Tags: php, tinymce

A simple question, but can't seem to find the answer to it..

As the question says I want the characters <>"' not encoded in TinyMCE.. because it messes up the rendering of my CMS.

Yes I know why the arrows are encoded, but in this case I need them not to.

I tried the following, but that doesn't do the trick:

```
tinymce.init({
        ...
        entity_encoding : "raw"
});
```

Edit:

I want to be able to use Variables like the following

$oUser->fname
$oUser->lname

Because of the encoding this won't function on the CMS System used, also the CMS sytemm uses SMARTY Engine if that is of any relevance here so the variables are in bracelets.

e.g. [{$foo->value}]

**TinyMCE**

majorVersion : '3',
minorVersion : '5.7',
releaseDate : '2012-09-20',

Comment: What exactly is encoded how and how does it mess up your rendering?

Comment: What version of tinyMCE?

Comment: I have updated my Question. I would like to use variables like $oUser->name, $oUser->mail and so on for Email Templates or other CMS pages.. the encoding causes trouble with the CMS System

Comment: why are you using tinyMCE to edit code?? its designed for html

Comment: Because I wanna make my Content more Personal and atrackt more customers?! besides I am not doing any programming in TinyMCE! I just want to output certain Variables which are already available on the page used... This makes total sense and this used to work in the past but since the update of the CMS, I had to change my Editor which resulted in problems like this.

Comment: Ah, this makes sense. Hmm, not sure what to recommend..... the ideal solution would be a regex that applies `html_entity_decode()` only within the smarty tags before the HTML is interpreted by Smarty. Generally turning entities of in the editor is bound to create trouble because anything like this: `<xyz>` would be interpreted as a tag - and consequently disappear from the editor

Comment: @Dagon he's editing a Smarty template. That does look like a legitimate use of TinyMCE to me

Comment: That does work, but it is not clean solution in my opinion, it might happen in the future where some encoded characters should not be decoded.. and there are about 100 CMS Pages that of which 50 orso have variables in it.. that would mean that I would need to edit my CMS Templates on multiple levels in order to get that working. Thanks for the try anyway.

Comment: The very cleanest approach would be to change the way Smarty interprets object operators, to something that doesn't use a HTML special character, say from `->` to, say `#-` or whatever. Not sure whether that can be done without hacking Smarty, though.